# Is this Hasse Diagram correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, partial-functions

I have the following question

Let, A = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} and (A, R) is a POSET where R is the partial order a ⊆ b.

I have drawn this Hasse diagram .

[image: Hasse diagram]

Is my answer correct ? 
And what the maximal and the minimal elements are ?

Comment: You are missing a few lines.  In particular is $\{2,3\}$ a subset of anything else in your list?  What does it mean to be a maximal element?  Are there any good candidates for that?  How about minimal?  Remember the difference between the words **maximal** and **maximum**.  Maximal is that there is nothing bigger than it and there can be multiple maximal elements.  Maximum on the other hand it must be the unique biggest element.

Comment: Yes, i want to know about what the maximal and minimal elements are  .. is that correct if  maximal should {1,2,3,4} and minimal  {1},{2},{3},{4} ? And in my list {2,3} is just a subset of {1,2,3,4}

Comment: And so if $\{2,3\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$... what should your picture have to reflect that information.  and yes, you are correct on the maximal and minimal elements except $\{4\}$ isn't actually an element of your set... is it?  So, is $\{4\}$ really a minimal element here if its not even an element of your set to begin with?

Comment: I'm confused about that . i think i'm wrong .. is that correct if i add a edge  between {2,3} and {1,2,3,4} ? and sorry for that because {4} isn't there .. the minimals are just {1},{2},{3}